# function argument generics set in anonymous class instance

Tags: java, generics

I need some help with generics, the goal is to create an onSuccess/onError callbacks that get an object as a arguments, the object type is set when creating the anonymous class that wraps the onSuccess/onError functions.

**The interface**

```
public interface OnDataResponse<T> {
   void onSuccess(T response);
   void onError(String data, ResponseError error);
}
```

The call that creates the listener, setting the argument type of onSuccess to be `CreateUserResponse`

```
createUser(new Operation.OnDataResponse<CreateUserResponse>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(CreateUserResponse response) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onError(String data, ResponseError error) {
   }
 };)
```

implementation of createUser()

```
public void createUser(OnDataResponse responseListener) {

           //performing the task asynchronously
           String data 
           // if successfull, create an object of type T
           //(CreateUserResponse in this case)
           // try to parse data from json to object
           //create instance of T
           T tInstance = new Gson().fromJson(data, type);

           // call the listener, providing the expected object
           responseListener.onSuccess(tInstance)
}
```

T is undefined inside `createUser()`

Any suggesstions on how to improve and make it work?

Comment: Try with the following signature:`public <T> void createUser(OnDataResponse<T> responseListener, Class<T> type)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide type in method or probably better in OnDataResponse if it can be used there:

```
public <T> void createUser(Class<T> type, OnDataResponse responseListener) { ... }
```

Comment: How can I provide the type from withing onDataResponse? I tried making it an abstract class with an implemented function that returns the type of T, but how do I return the type of T?

Comment: passing it to it's constructor? is there a way to get the type of T in runtime?

Comment: in interface you can return e.g. Class<T> getType(), so later you will only run T tInstance = new Gson().fromJson(data, responseListener.getType()); and factory will be on listener